# Declaring pointer to method with decltype in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, gcc, methods, clang

There are some differences between `clang` and `gcc`. One of them is how they treat the pointers to method. Given the following code:

```
template <typename T_Class, typename T_Ret, typename ... Args>
void store_method(T_Class *object, T_Ret (T_Class::*method)(Args ... args));

class SomeObjectWithPotentiallyLongName {
     int commonly_used_method(int var);
     void register_method() {
          /* The code below is okay for gcc with -std=gnu++11. But clang
           * says:
           * 'reference to non-static member function must be called' */
          store_method(this, commonly_used_method);
          /* To make this fine for clang (and also - gcc), I have to 
           * extend previous line as next */
          store_method(this, &SomeObjectWithPotentiallyLongName::commonly_used_method);
     }
}
```

The code above shows the necessity to extend code in many places to make it compiled by clang, while it can be much neat and as clear with gcc.

The most obvious way is to write some macro which would turn `this` and `method_name` to something like `&TypeOfThis::method_name`.

My idea was to use `decltype`:

```
#define STORE_METHOD(method) store_method(this, (decltype(*this))::method)

void SomeObjectWithPotentiallyLongName::register_method() {
     STORE_METHOD(commonly_used_method);
}
```

But this code yield the following error with `clang`:

> 'decltype(*this)' (aka 'SomeObjectWithPotentiallyLongName &') is not a class, namespace, or enumeration

Is there any way to build such macro? If not, is there an other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well `T &` is not a type that is usable in this context (as pointed out in the comments it is still a type), it's a reference. You can use `std::remove_reference<...>::type` ([documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/remove_reference/)) to remove the reference and get the `T` type instead:

```
typedef std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type T;
```

And then use:

```
T::method
```

Comment: `T&` is a type. It may not be the type you want, but it is a type.

Answer (score 3):

You missed `&` in your macro. Moreover [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) may yield a qualified reference type, so you should use [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) to remove reference and qualifiers:

```
#define STORE_METHOD(method)\
    store_method(\
        this,\
        &std::decay<decltype(*this)>::type::method\
    )
```

Or `std::decay_t` in C++14:

```
#define STORE_METHOD(method)\
    store_method(\
        this,\
        &std::decay_t<decltype(*this)>::method\
    )
```